# What does "call past" mean?

Tags: phrases

What does the expression "***call past***" mean? See some usages below:

> I called past the supermarket on the way home from the office.
>
> He just called past and asked to gather the team in the canteen.
>
> Gary called past to check if Jimmy was doing okay.

Comment: I have never heard this expression.

Comment: @Mahnax--Neither have I.

Comment: @simchona Too localized....?

Comment: @Mahnax Or NARQ.

Comment: @simchona Okay, flagging as NARQ.

Comment: How can this be a NARQ?

Comment: Context? Could you tell us where the example statements occur? That can help, I suppose. If they are online sources, can you provide links?

Comment: I think it's just a "bowlderisation" of [call by/stop by](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+called+by%2CI+called+past&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3)

Comment: @FumbleFingers how could "call by" or "stop by" possibly be considered offensive?

Comment: @phoog: You got me! I put it in quotes because I knew it wasn't quite the right word. Should have been ["malapropism"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malapropism). But still in quotes, because I'm not sure it's a typical example of even that.

Answer (score 4):

I grew up with it. I can't believe that it is only an Australian saying. It does mean "to stop in"

Comment: I.e. to *call in* or *stop by*?  In my experience, *stop in* is opposed to *go out*.  That's the problem with short prepostional phrases; they have too many possible meanings.

Comment: Believe it.  I've encountered a few Australians who had a hard time believing similar things (for example, that Americans don't pronounce "aussie" as "ozzie", and that Americans don't use "beanie" to mean a winter cap -- although that seems to have changed recently).

Comment: @phoog. After a night, a reread and a thought, I realise that you are right. I can't stand the americans saying 'uh-see' insteed of 'oz-ze'. But seriously, it's hard to remember, or even know, what is only local/regional when we have tv and audio shows from around the world. I am sure that many words we aussies use are from the States, but many Americans don't seem to know them. But then the same goes for what we think of as from Engliand. Other phrases that mean the same are 'popped in', 'called by', 'popped by', 'called into'. Many others I can't think of ATM.

Comment: As an American (US), I've never said or heard "aussie" pronounced as "uh-see". What seems common to me is to pronounce it as "aw-zee".

Answer (score 3):

*Call past* is equivalent to *stop in* while on the way somewhere else, as far as I recall its usage in books, films, and "BritCom" TV shows.  (*Stop in* is American for *stop by* or *visit*.)

Here are two instances in books.  Notes: [Shirramore](http://www.geody.com/geospot.php?world=terra&ufi=-2607718&alc=shr) is in central Scotland.  [McMullen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sean_McMullen) was born in Sale, Victoria, Australia.

[Chambers's journal](http://books.google.com/books?id=Ha8aAQAAMAAJ&q=%22call+past%22+beautiful&dq=%22call+past%22+beautiful&hl=en&sa=X&ei=x3nrTvDtCoSsiQKgq4CDBA&ved=0CD4Q6AEwAzge) 1939, p. 272 -

> In any case, I'll call past and drop Archie at Shirramore, where he seems anxious to call!

Sean McMullen, [Glass Dragons](http://books.google.com/books?id=X54PyNR3z2IC&pg=PA94&dq=%22call+past%22+bright&hl=en&sa=X&ei=tnfrTouZBOiWiAKhybX8Aw&sqi=2&ved=0CFQQuwUwBA#v=onepage&q=%22call%20past%22%20bright&f=false), p. 94 -

> "I meant it when I said call past if ever you travel here again," she insisted.

Comment: I've never heard it or heard of it. Perhaps I don't watch enough BritCom TV shows.

Comment: @Barrie - Me too, since here in the U.S., only a tiny fraction of the many BritCom shows are shown.  Anyhow, I've added two examples (from books) to my answer.

Comment: It seems to be an Australian saying, so maybe it's not that prevalent in BritComs.  AusComs, perhaps?

Comment: @phoog - I've added note re McMullen born in Victoria